# Music doesn't play when some apps are open in the background - ios cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have encountered an issue with my ios cocos2d app, that while certain apps are open in the background, my app's music doesn't play.
After I terminate those apps from the background, the music works again.

I use the following mode for CDAudioManager:

```
[[CDAudioManager sharedManager] setMode:kAMM_FxPlusMusicIfNoOtherAudio];
```

I use this in order to allow the user to play background music from his music player.

When I change this mode to kAMM_FxPlusMusic for example, my app's music is played even if those apps are open - which is great. However, the music from the music player in this case is paused, which is not what I want.

The main question is:

Why do some apps cause my app's music to not play, and can I do something about it while still allowing the user to play music from his music player?

Comment: sounds like those apps request exclusive audio access, meaning they either need it (radio apps etc) or they're simply not programmed to be cooperative with other apps playing music (games?). Is this on iOS 7?